# How to disable auto generated routes by Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am upgrading an existing application to Rails 5.2.

Old application is using Paperclip for file storage and I am trying to move that to ActiveStorage.

My app expose an API that allows users to securely upload files (using key/secret pairs to sign requests).

When I installed ActiveStorage I found several new routes

```
      rails_service_blob GET  /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET  /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

How I can disable those routes to not allow random uploads to my app.

Answer (score 15):

To secure remove all ActiveStorage routes without side effects add this to config/application.rb:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
   ...
   initializer(:remove_activestorage_routes, after: :add_routing_paths) {|app|
      app.routes_reloader.paths.delete_if {|path| path =~ /activestorage/}}
   ...
end
```

I advise against replacing `require 'rails/all'` in config/application.rb with a list of rails gems grabbed from rails source code, which is often recommended.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely works as I've used this in my app to remove the routes. I wish they were optional, not all apps that use ActiveStorage need the public routes. This should be marked as accepted answer!

Comment: I do recommend replacing `require 'rails/all'`, as this is what the `rails new myapp --skip-active-storage` generator command does and is the convention for not loading any of the other frameworks (e.g. actioncable, activejob, actionmailbox). The answer here (modifying the routes) will use up resources loading the activestorage framework when it is not needed, and will prevent other Rails developers used to the convention from looking at the top of `config/application.rb` to determine which frameworks are loaded.

Comment: In case of `action_mailbox` too just use it like this: `... path =~ /activestorage|actionmailbox/ ...`

Comment: In Rails 6.1 there will be a `Rails.configuration.active_storage.draw_routes` flag that can be set to false, but until then this works great!